# Why the stack is not pushing?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
 public class Rpie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String rpie = input.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(rpie);

        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        while (string.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String tkn = string.nextToken();
            if (tkn.equals("+") || tkn.equals("-") || tkn.equals("*")
                    || tkn.equals("/")) {
                stack.push(tkn);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(stack);

    }
}
```

Why the stack doesn't push the strings when it reads + , -, * or / ?

It outputs an empty stack.

Comment: I suggest you start by printing information in your loop - for example


`if(...){`
`System.out.println("got " + tkn);`

` stack.push(tkn);`


or something like that. this way you'll know better what might cause your problem... post the results if you need more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. The tokenizer needs spaces to separate your input. So Something like:

1 + 2

will push `+` to the stack. Note the spaces!

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation:

```
public StringTokenizer(String str)

Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. 
The tokenizer uses the default delimiter set, which is " \t\n\r\f": 
the space character, 
the tab character, 
the newline character, 
the carriage-return character, 
and the form-feed character. 

Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.
```

So this means that if you don't specify a delimiter, you NEED one of those default delimiters otherwise if there is not even one of them in the string you give to your program, like say you type "1+2-3*4/5", then there is only one token and it is '1+2-3*4/5', but if you put let's say the space character like this "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5", then your program will print "[+, -, *, /]" because those are the only ones you allow to go in your stack because of the if.

I hope this is clear enough for you mate.